# Is there any API for getting location of the message received for bot building?

Tags: bots

I want to get the location of the message received on messenger.
I want to build a bot which will use the location of the user.

Comment: You're going to need to add more detail or else no one will be able to help you.

Comment: If a user types a message i just the location of the pc from where that message was sent

Comment: If a user types a message where? In a generic messenger program?

Comment: i want to create a bot,so whenever a client uses a bot and sends a message to a bot then i want to locate clients location.